# Azure best practice for creating associated infrastructure

Tags: azure, cloud

When working in azure and leveraging all the PaaS offerings like queues and tables, I often face the dilemma of whether I should create these resource on-demand, or up-front as part of provisioning.

For example, let's say I have a worker role that receives message from a queue and then persists data to a table. I have two options

**Option 1 - Up-front provisioning**
As part of my provisioning process I could create both the queue and the table via the likes of a powershell script. In the code, at runtime, it would then expect these resources to exist, and if they didn't it would raise an exception.

Pros

- The service doesn't need administrator privileges, as it doesn't need to create anything
- All provision work happens in a single place (the provisioning script) rather than being scattered through the code.

Cons

- The service cannot be "self-healing". What I mean by this is that, in the event that a required resource doesn't exist (e.g. a queue or a table), or maybe doesn't exist in the form needed, the service cannot recover from this automatically. Instead it requires manual intervention.

**Option 2 - On-demand**

At runtime, as resources are needed, they are created if they don't exist.

Pros

- The running service can create whatever it needs, and as such will be more robust and require less intervention.

Cons

- The code now has elevated privileges that could cause some security concerns

---

I find myself facing this issue, mostly when dealing with queues or topics/subscriptions. There are two conflicting reasons for this

1. I like to create a Shared Access Key for each queue and only grant the required permission. For example in the above scenario, where reading from the queue, I would create a SAK with read-only permissions.
2. I like to have things automatically created as and when needed, particularly during development. This makes things so much easier, and stuff just works.

What I'd like to know is, is there any recommended approach, either from the Azure team or from the wider community, on which option to use? Can anyone give me any definitive reasons to choose one option over the other?

Comment: Unfortunately, opinion-based questions aren't a fit here. And there are several ways to tackle this type of question, with no single right answer.

Comment: Thanks David, I thought about that before asking the question but concluded that surely best practice should prevail over simple opinions, right?

Answer (score 0):

We used to create Storage Containers and Queues as part of provisioning. But that was a pain to work with locally: developers sometimes got caught out by random exceptions thrown (and swallowed) by unrelated parts of the code. At one instance we have wasted a day just to realise that a storage container is not created locally.

Then we have switched for "create on demand" and never regretted.

If you are talking about storage queues and tables, than there is no need to elevate the access rights - creating of containers/queues/tables can be done with the same access key as your application gets for work with a storage account.

If you talk about storage accounts and databases, then we do this as part of provisioning - creating them requires a management certificate and a few calls to Azure Management API. And this is a lot more extra work for something that is never deleted/modified. Also, if your application suddenly looses access to a blob storage, then something is very wrong and attempt to auto-heal will not do any good.